# How do I create a 'selection' criteria list' that will then dictate which posts are generated when the user presses search?

Tags: posts, widgets

I'm very new to WordPress so please bear with me!

I'm currently in the process of building a site for work. Our 'vision' is that we have three lists of options. People would select one option from each list, and then press search. That would generate a page full of posts which the user could then select from.

For example, from list A they could select 1, from list B they could select 2, and from list C they could select 3. The combination of 1, 2 and 3 would then generate posts that are tagged as being relevant to 1, 2 and 3.

Any thoughts or help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is a little off. *Search* implies providing a search word of phrase and receiving matched when it is found in content.

What you describe is commonly called filters or facets (sometimes faceted search).

Implementing it would depend on your exact data architecture. You might use custom taxonomies, but really there aren't details in your question to guess about that.

There are some plugins that implement faceting, but none that I have used myself.

Overall you need:
 - more research on how your data will be structured;
 - more research on how faceting will be implemented for it.

No quick answer possible here.